# What may cause NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I spent about two hours searching for the solution but found nothing. As far as I know `.nextLine()` should wait for input and it usually does. But in this code, it throws `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found`. Can anyone explain what may cause this issue?

Please notice that I'm new to java.

Here's a troubling piece of code

```
private void interactiveMode() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Launching remote collection manager");
        try (Scanner userCommandReader = new Scanner(System.in)){                                                      
            System.out.println("Collection is ready for formatting");
            System.out.println("Waiting for input. Type help for list of commands");
            Thread.sleep(1000);                    

            String testString = userCommandReader.nextLine();
            System.out.println(testString);
        }catch (Exception e ) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Here's full Exception just in case:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at client.ConnectToServer.interactiveMode(ConnectToServer.java:81) //line 81:String  testString = userCommandReader.nextLine();
    at client.ConnectToServer.server_tunnel(ConnectToServer.java:44)
    at client.Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

Here's main method that calls two other methods

```
System.out.println("Preparing Auth tool"); //Part of main method
boolean isAuthorized = Auth.serverAuth(outcoming); //when I'm skipping `serverAuth()`, interactiveMode works just fine. 
System.out.println("isAuthorized="+isAuthorized);                        
if(isAuthorized) {interactiveMode();}
```

So my guess is that there's my bad somewhere over here in serverAuth method
public static Boolean serverAuth(Socket socket) {

```
System.out.println("[WARNING] Launching Auth tool");                
        try (Scanner authScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            DataOutputStream authOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream authIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());) {                            
                boolean loginStage=true;
                boolean passwordStage=true;
                while (loginStage) {
                    System.out.println("Enter your login:");
                    String user_login=authScanner.nextLine();
                    authOut.writeUTF(user_login);
                    int serverLoginAnswer = authIn.read();
                    if (serverLoginAnswer == 1) {
                        loginStage=false;
                        while (passwordStage) {                         
                            System.out.println("Enter your password:");
                            String user_password = authScanner.nextLine();                            
                            String encrypted_user_password = ConnectToServer.encrypt_data(user_password);
                            authOut.writeUTF(encrypted_user_password);                            
                            int serverAuthAnswer = authIn.read();
                            if (serverAuthAnswer == 1) {
                                passwordStage=false;
                                System.out.println("You were authorized");                                
                                return true;                            
                                }
                            else if (serverAuthAnswer == 0) {
                                System.out.println("[!]Wrong password");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (serverLoginAnswer==0) {
                            System.out.println("[!]Incorrect login");                                                        
                    }                                        
                }

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("[!]Incorrect input");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the issue is that `Scanner` is getting closed because of `try-with-resources` syntax. Note that once `userCommandReader` is closed, `System.in` is also closed which can not be opened again. Do it as follows:

```
private void interactiveMode() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Launching remote collection manager");
    Scanner userCommandReader = new Scanner(System.in)                                                    
    System.out.println("Collection is ready for formatting");
    System.out.println("Waiting for input. Type help for list of commands");
    Thread.sleep(1000);                    

    String testString = userCommandReader.nextLine();
    System.out.println(testString);    
}
```

Comment: But now the scanner is not closed

Comment: @BorislavStoilov - You must never close `Scanner` for `System.in`. As I've mentioned once the Scanner for `System.in` is closed, `System.in` is also closed which can not be opened again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but your application is either failing to read from the std in, or it is just slow to do so.

Try waiting for the new line and see if that makes any difference.

```
    System.out.println("Launching remote collection manager");
    try (Scanner userCommandReader = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.println("Collection is ready for formatting");
        System.out.println("Waiting for input. Type help for list of commands");
        while(userCommandReader.hasNextLine()) {
            String testString = userCommandReader.nextLine();
            System.out.println(testString);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I removed the `Thread.sleep` it is not needed

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately, it didn't help 
I've managed to find a "possible issue"
I don't know how to post code in comments, so I'll drop it with next Answer to this question
Nevermind, I'll add it to the main question